# VSCode not auto completing python module import

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

My VSCode editor suddenly stopped listing suggestion when am running import statements.

ie.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404, get_list_or_404, HttpResponse
```

normally when I type:

```
from django.
```

it should suggest all packages in django or when I type

```
from django.shortcuts import
```

it again should suggest render, get_object_or_404 etc.

But this is not more happening. I have to painstakingly type these out myself.

please any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: the latest PyLance needs VSC v1.50

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53070679/6505847

Comment: @prynet -Which extensions did you use? Could you please provide us with the content of your settings file "settings.json"? Since python's auto-completion function is provided by the "Python" extension, please try to reinstall it.

Answer (score 1):

That should change with VSCode 1.71 and [issue 53715](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/53715)  which describes a similar problem:

> Intellisense completions in VSCode are only shown after typing the first letter of a method.
> But I don't always remember this - I often only remember some other parts of a name.
>
> Example: If I type
>
> ```py
> import os 
> os.dir
> ```
>
> I would like to get "mkdir" or "makedirs" as a suggestion. This works as expected in VS Community2017 (or other IDEs like pycharm):
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19992955/42380505-74e7b554-812e-11e8-83bc-ece31654ee40.png]
>
> In VSCode 1.25.0 (with python extension 2018.06) I only get this:
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19992955/42380531-84cd182e-812e-11e8-887f-c752623cd53d.png]
>
> Only if I enter "`os.m`" I get suggestions for "`mkdir`" or "`makedirs`".
>
> It's nice that after the initial letter I can enter any string so that "`os.md`" shows the suggestions I want but I don't always remember the first letter of a method.

This is fixed with [PR 152292](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/152292)

> ### Add an option to expose the allowMidWordMatch as a setting
>
> `editor.suggest.matchOnWordStartOnly`
>
> When enabled IntelliSense filtering requires that the first character matches on a word start, e.g `c` on `Console` or `WebContext` but *not* on `description`.
>
> When disabled IntelliSense will show more results but still sorts them by match quality.

This is released to [VScode Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) today.

Answer (score -3):

I reinstalled VScode and was quite careful with extension installation. Everything is working fine now guys, thanks.

Comment: what did you do?