# Visual Studio Code - Intellisense not working on SSH server even though it's installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

So for some reason my intellisense is not working.

I tried the solutions suggested here [Visual Studio Code: Intellisense not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389852/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working).

The solution that seems to help most people is adding `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [ "${workspaceFolder}/customModule" ]`, didn't work. Also VS Code says it doesn't recognize `python.pythonPath` when I add it.

Auto-complete not working, screen capture didn't capture my cursor, but it's right after `argparse.`, which should give the option to auto-complete with a list that includes: `ArgumentParser`:
[image]

Remote server installed extensions:
[image]

**Settings.json**
This is `settings.json` on remote server

```
{
    "remote.autoForwardPortsSource": "output",
    "python.languageServer": "None",
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
    "python.analysis.diagnosticMode": "workspace",
}
```

**Setup:**

- Running using Conda env
- Linux remote server

**Note:**
Something else off is my "find declaration of function or class" is also not working.

Comment: have you installed https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh?

Comment: @gftea on remote or local?

Comment: do use vs insiders?https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/?

Comment: @Gooby, on remote, local only need ssh client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the first solutions are kind of obvious, but ill add them anyway,

1. Removing reinstalling it both locally and remotely
2. Make sure VS code is updated to its last version
3. In `settings.json`, set a language server in `"python.languageServer"`. The Language Server includes: `Jedi`(build-in Python extension ), `Microsoft`, `Pylance`, since you have already installed `Pylance`, let's start with that one (if that doesnt work, try the others).
4. set your `python.pythonPath` to the path returned in your terminal for `which python3`

Comment: answer 3 was the solution. I have to wait 7 hours to give the bounty.

Comment: no problem mate, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, even though Pylance etc were installed on my local machine, I had to back to the VSCode extensions window, and install them again on the SSH machine.