# vs code not showing suggestion in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I work with `mysql.connector` it doesn't show me suggestions.

What should I do?

[image]

Comment: I hope you can find solution here:
[Visual Studio Code: Intellisense not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389852/visual-studio-code-intellisense-not-working)

Comment: Please post the code as text no an image.

Comment: Whether the mysql package has been installed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Please use the `PyMySQL` package.

First install the **PyMySQL** package using the `pip` command

```
pip install PyMySQL
```

Then modify the code as follows

```
import pymysql

mydb = pymysql.connect(
    host = 'localhost',
    user = 'root',
    password = ''
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = 'create database py_university_db'

mycursor.e
```

Now everything works

[image]